# Quantum effects are weak in molecular modeling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

I started to develop a molecule modeling application. The early results show that quantum effects are negligable in **most** cases. (I mean bond orbit superpositions, effect of antisymmetrization).
Is this true?

Comment: It's possible this might fit better on the Chemistry stack exchange. Possibly relevant to your question though is that I think I remember it beingt the case that if you plotted the electron density for a molecule it looked basically like that of the atoms to a good approx.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the last part.

Comment: Since the point of Density Functional Theory is to apply a full quantum picture to molecular or solid binding, I really can't agree with this assertion. Otherwise folks wouldn't bother with the pain and computational cost of DFT. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157397000835 is a fairly old review but reasonable on the basics.

Comment: What Jon Custer said. But also atomic bonds are quantum effects. Do you mean that you can model these by H has 1 bond, C has 4, and so on. Quantum mechanics has little to add to this type of rule in most cases? Or perhaps you have in mind some more complex rules? If so, the same question applies.

Comment: I meant I can compute quite accurate values (bond angles e.g.) without using superposed states or antisymmetrised wavefunctions. All I used is electrostatics with pointlike nuclei and Gauss-like charge distibutions (as electron orbits).

Comment: sp3 hybridization is a quantum effect, so my qurstion became pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sp3 hybridization is a quantum effect, so my qurstion became pointless.